# jupyter notebook running issues

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am running some python code using a jupyter notebook. The notebook should take a couple of days to finish. After a couple of running hours a massage is shown: "Error rendering Jupyter widget: missing widget manager." The hourglass at the chrome tab keeps on running, but the * symbol next to the cell no longer appears, only [] is appeared. I have two questions: 1. is the notebook still running? 2. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you provide the notebook? Or versions of jupyter/python that you're using? Is it Jupyter notebook or juypter lab? This can be due to many reasons, e.g. notebook renders a javascript that stalls the browser. Or the kernel just might have died/crashed. What's the output supposed to look like?

Comment: Hi, Python version is 3.8.5. It is Jupyter Notebook. The output will create an excel file.

Comment: Hi Jakub, Python version is 3.8.5. It is Jupyter Notebook. The output will create an excel file